# What do people mean when they say back-end Java with front-end PHP or something?

Tags: java, php, mysql

I've been programming for a while now, and I am pretty familiar with Java and PHP and websites.  What I'm confused about is how programmers use them together.  I hear about how Facebook and Google use all sorts of languages like Python, C, Java, PHP all for one product, but I'm just confused on how that would be possible.

Also, another side question:
What work exactly do software engineers do when working for large online companies like Twitter and Facebook?  Most of the code deals with database and information, and so what major level programming, besides what can be learned online with a few tutorials, needs to be done on the server side?

Comment: I am not a very active StackExchange user but I think this question doesn't belong here

Comment: I'm pretty sure the technology at Facebook isn't trivial. [Here's a sample](https://github.com/facebook), and [here's another one](https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=24413138919).

Comment: That just means the product is comprised of multiple services, each written in a language of choice, choice depending on whether the language is suited for the service performance/time/maintainability wise. It doesn't mean that there's 1 program that has mashed source coming from various languages.

Comment: It's worth noting that Facebook have a *huge* number of servers (though not nearly as many as Google). They're kept running continuously at very high CPU loads, I believe running C++ code.

Answer (score 6):

This is an incredibly broad question, but here's a shot at a vague answer.  Often times large applications will have a number of components.  For instance, you may have some sort of reporting engine, business logic, web interface, desktop interface, web service API, mobile interface, etc, etc, etc.  Each of these could, in theory be written in a different language and communicate via a database or something like a web service.

To your second question.  At large companies there is a great deal of work to be done to maintain stability, develop new features, fix bugs as they are discovered and work to increase efficiency etc.  Facebook, for instance (and Google) employs a large number of software engineers to help them deal with the massive amounts of volume they receive on a daily basis.

**Edit** Here's a bit more clarification and a direct answer to your question.

> Most of the code deals with database and information, and so what major level programming, besides what can be learned online with a few tutorials, needs to be done on the server side?

The truth is, for the most part, the high-level principals are the same.  You could pretty easily build a Facebook clone after doing some basic PHP/MySQL tutorials on the web.  Here's the difference: your clone would die before it reached a fraction of the users Facebook sees on a daily basis.  It would be slow, unreliable and people would leave because their data would be consistently hacked through SQL injection and other malicious attacks.  And that's not even talking about distributed computing. So, yes, from a high-level, that's all you need to know.  The implementation and reality is much, much more complex.

Comment: Is that related with term `three tire` ?

Comment: Then there's the addition of code transformation - Facebook for example has a compiler that turns its PHP into C for faster processing.

Answer (score 0):

As you might expect, larger "websites" are not built in the traditional sense that you have some PHP code, a few HTML templates and a database, since this kind of architecture has severe issues scaling to thousands of concurrent users.

What you can to to mitigate this is split the website out in several components:

1. Load balancers that distribute requests to several App servers
2. App servers which generate the UI and handle user actions
3. Middleware servers that handle business logic and distribute it among DB servers
4. DB servers that store data in some way

Every component of this system might be implemented in a different language and you might even have different app servers depending on request type (e.g. mobile devices).

This type of system is called [Multitier Architectures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture). You can also find academic books on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Most complex products consist of numerous pieces. For example, StackExchange has code that runs in your browser that's written in JavaScript so it can run in your browser. But the code that builds the web pages doesn't run in a browser and so isn't written in JavaScript. And if complex database queries are needed, they're likely to be in SQL. And so in. Each piece of the big puzzle is implement in the language most appropriate for what that piece does and the environment in which it runs.

Thank about GMail. There's a in-browser piece that's written in JavaScript. There's also a web server, a database, a mail server, a bulk storage system, indexing, and many, many other pieces.

Answer (score 0):

this is the actual answer you are looking for
you are confused because you dont see how using the C and C++ applications in websites but I want to tell you that, they are used for many things... like, when you upload a image in facebook containing pornographic content, then php wont validate that image, what they will do is that execute a program by passing the address of that image by parameters and that application will validate the image... and some data should be stored for future use, so that application uses the common database that the site is using, if we upload a image in googleplus, then it will load tag sugestion to some part where people's faces are seen, it is done by that app, it will save the image data to the common database which google is using and php takes that information from there, this is the technique of developing much more functional websites...
like, i have made a program to shutdown my home computer while working on localhost:

```
<?php
$command="shutdown -s -f -t 5";
shell_exec($command);
?>
```

this script once run in apache will shut the server down similarly you can pass the parameters into some apps like if you want to create email account in command line for your own server which dont have Cpanel installed...

and the answer of second part of your question:
actually software engineers are hired so that they will develop some apps that can be run in a server for increasing the functionality of the website... like if there would be only webscripting language for websites, then google couldnot recognise the face neither facebook, and artificial intillegence would not be possible for websites..

this post may clear your confusion...